# How to solve non linear system of array using scipy

Tags: python, scipy, implicit, differential-equations, nonlinear-optimization

I wrote a class with the aims to solve the system of differential equations (given in numpy.array form) , in order to solve the non linear system I'm using the `scipy.optimize.fsolve` using an example find here in one post, the method works fine with single equation while fail if I'm try to using for a system of differential equations ! I wrote a  **Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**
in this way you can verify and deep understand how the class works!

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve , newton_krylov
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class ImpRK4 :

    def __init__(self, fun , t0, tf, dt , y0):
        self.func = fun
        self.t0=t0
        self.tf=tf
        self.dt=dt
        self.u0=y0
        self.n = round((tf-t0)/dt)
        self.time  = np.linspace(self.t0, self.tf, self.n+1 )
        self.u     = np.array([self.u0  for i in range(self.n+1) ])

    def f(self,ti,ui):
         return  np.array([functions(ti,ui) for functions in self.func])     

    def solve(self): 


       for i in range(len(self.time)-1):

            def equations(variable):
                k1,k2 = variable
                f1 = -k1 + self.f(self.time[i]+ (0.5+np.sqrt(3)/6)* self.dt , self.u[i]+0.25*self.dt* k1+ (0.25+ np.sqrt(3)/6)*self.dt*k2) 
                f2 = -k2 + self.f(self.time[i]+ (0.5-np.sqrt(3)/6)* self.dt , self.u[i]+(0.25-np.sqrt(3)/6)*self.dt *k1 + 0.25*self.dt* k2)
                return np.array([f1,f2]).ravel() #.reshape(2,)  


            k1 , k2 = fsolve(equations,(2,2)) #(self.u[i],self.u[i]))
            self.u[i+1] = self.u[i] + self.dt/2* (k1 + k2)


       plt.plot(self.time,self.u)
       plt.show()    
def main():



func00 = lambda t,u : -10*(t-1)*u[0]

func01 = lambda t,u : u[1] 
func02 = lambda t,u : (1-u[0]**2)*u[1] - u[0]

func0x = np.array([func00])
func0 = np.array([func01,func02])



t0 = 0. 
tf = 2.      
u0 = y01   
dt = 0.008 

y01 = np.array([1.,1.])
diffeq = ImpRK4(func0,t0,tf,dt,y01)    


#y0  = np.array([np.exp(-5)])
#diffeq.solve()
#diffeq = ImpRK4(func0x,t0,tf,dt,y0) ## with single equations works
diffeq.solve()



if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

**EDIT**
No I'm sorry but is not what I was looking for ... basically when I have a system of equations I have to get K1 and K2 of the same dimension of `self.u[i]`

Answer (score 0):

For your two equations, your `self.f()` function returns an array of length 2. Therefore, `f1` and `f2` are both arrays of length 2.
The result is then that `equations()` returns a flattened array of length 4.
However, `fsolve` expects `equations` (it's `func` argument) to return an array of length 2, since your initial guess `x0=(2,2)` is an array of length 2.

I'm not sure if the following is what you're trying to do in your context, but you can fix this error by replacing:

```
f1 = -k1 + self.f(self.time[i]+ (0.5+np.sqrt(3)/6)* self.dt , self.u[i]+0.25*self.dt* k1+ (0.25+ np.sqrt(3)/6)*self.dt*k2)
f2 = -k2 + self.f(self.time[i]+ (0.5-np.sqrt(3)/6)* self.dt , self.u[i]+(0.25-np.sqrt(3)/6)*self.dt *k1 + 0.25*self.dt* k2)
```

with the following code (adding references [0], [1] at the line end):

```
f1 = -k1 + self.f(self.time[i]+ (0.5+np.sqrt(3)/6)* self.dt , self.u[i]+0.25*self.dt* k1+ (0.25+ np.sqrt(3)/6)*self.dt*k2)[0]
f2 = -k2 + self.f(self.time[i]+ (0.5-np.sqrt(3)/6)* self.dt , self.u[i]+(0.25-np.sqrt(3)/6)*self.dt *k1 + 0.25*self.dt* k2)[1]
```

Comment: and if instead of (2,2) I give in input `(self.u[i],self.u[i])`

Comment: No I'm sorry but is not what I was looking for ... basically when I have a system of equations I have to get K1 and K2 of the same dimension of `self.u[i]`